# How do I get a list of all file paths inside a folder in node

Tags: node.js

I have a folder called Videos and inside Videos there are more Folders named RoomA, RoomB... etc. Inside those Room folders, there are videos stored. I need a way of retrieving all the `paths` to the videos so I can upload them.

This is running on ubuntu

The folder would look something like this:

```
Videos
   -RoomA
      --video1.mp4
   -RoomB
      --video2.mp4
      --video3.mp4
```

Running the script while in the Videos folder should return something like:

```
[Videos/RoomA/video1.mp4, Videos/RoomB/video2.mp4, Videos/RoomB/video3.mp4]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: is It running on a windows or Linux environment ?

Comment: already answered : https://gist.github.com/kethinov/6658166

Comment: What code have you tried?  Synchronous or Asynchronous file I/O?